# Как читать строку посимвольно?

Tags: c++, arduino

Мне прилетает по TCP `eff_10` и мне нужно чтобы `eff` был в `sections[0]`, а `10` в `sections[1]`. Но может еще прилететь `pixel 1 fcba03` которые также нужно засунуть в `sections[0,1,2]`
Что-то подобное я писал, для Serial, но я не знаю как читать строку по символьно.

```
void parseStringFromSerial() {
  int sectionIndex = 0;
  String section;

  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    delay(1);
    char incomingChar = Serial.read();
    if (incomingChar == '_' || incomingChar == '\n') {
      sections[sectionIndex] = section;
      section = "";
      ++sectionIndex;
    } else {
      section += incomingChar;
    }
  }
}
```

в питоне я бы сделал `message.split('_')`

Comment: я пытался поискать решение, но я запутался

Comment: Вы можете обращаться к символам строки по индексу, например, `message[0]`  это первый символ в строке

Comment: Спасибо не знал что так можно

Comment: У вас же наверняка есть какая-то строчная библиотека, вот и используйте её возможности: `strsep()`.